# Does jQuery v1.11 support latest Chrome, Firefox (2017)

Tags: jquery

Does jQuery v1.11 (released in 2014) support latest Chrome, Firefox (released in 2017).

While current jQuery supports latest Chrome, Firefox during development; once jQuery is not updated, older jQuery is not really tested with newer versions of Chrome, Firefox, and there is no information what exact version range is supported by jQuery v1.11, jQuery v1.10 etc.

P.S. Version of Google Chrome in 2014 32.x;
current version of now is 59.x
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history

Comment: Your making wrong assumptions. Yes it does.

Comment: Having similar issues here: jQuery functionality breaking in the latest browsers.